# How to navigate from custom browser to app in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, browser, payu

I integrated custom browser in my app for PayU integration. I am not sending any parameters to PayU URL (https://secure.payu.in/_payment ). I am doing (sending parameters to PayU) this at server side. I need only customization of browser, that's why I am using this one. This is working fine to me, but after payment success it is showing empty white screen. How to navigate to my app after this white empty screen.

How can I get URL of the custom browser?

ref link: https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-Custom-Browser/wiki/v5.2.2

dependency:

```
compile 'com.payu.custombrowser:payu-custom-browser:5.2.2'
```

code:

custombrowserxl:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/r_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/trans_overlay"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

custombrowser.java

```
 try {
            Class.forName("com.payu.custombrowser.Bank");
            final Bank bank = new Bank() {
                @Override
                public void registerBroadcast(BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter filter) {
                    mReceiver = broadcastReceiver;
                    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
                }

                @Override
                public void unregisterBroadcast(BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver) {
                    if(mReceiver != null){
                        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
                        mReceiver = null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onHelpUnavailable() {
                    findViewById(R.id.parent).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.trans_overlay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBankError() {
                    findViewById(R.id.parent).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.trans_overlay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onHelpAvailable() {
                    findViewById(R.id.parent).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            };
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("webView", R.id.webview);
            args.putInt("tranLayout",R.id.trans_overlay);
            args.putInt("mainLayout",R.id.r_layout);
            args.putBoolean("showCustom", true);
            bank.setArguments(args);
            findViewById(R.id.parent).bringToFront();
            try {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.cb_fade_in, R.anim.cb_face_out).add(R.id.parent, bank).commit();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                finish();
            }

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new PayUWebChromeClient(bank));
            webView.setWebViewClient(new PayUWebViewClient(bank));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void onSuccess() {

                    onSuccess("");
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public void onSuccess(final String result) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.putExtra("result", result);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                            finish();

                        }
//                }
                    });
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public void onFailure() {
                    onFailure("");
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public void onFailure(final String result) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.putExtra("result", result);
                            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, "PayU");

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            });
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        }

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

     String   PostData="UserUniqueID=" + UUUID + "&OrderID=" + orderid + "&PFID=" + pid + "&ReloadCash=" + reloadcash + "&DeviceID=" + DEVICEID ;

        webView.postUrl(WebUrl.Bankurl, PostData.getBytes());
      //Weburl.posturl is my server side bank url.
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        boolean disableBack = false;
        if(cancelTransaction){
            cancelTransaction = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("result", "Transaction canceled due to back pressed!");
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        try {
            Log.v("TAG_PAUSEURLL", "" + "PAUSEURL");
            Bundle bundle = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData;
            disableBack = bundle.containsKey("payu_disable_back") && bundle.getBoolean("payu_disable_back");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!disableBack) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you really want to cancel the transaction ?");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    cancelTransaction = true;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.destroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.payment_home);


    btnBuy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "ShowToast" }) @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(f_nm && f_pn  && f_email )
            {
                webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Integer randomNum = randInt(0, 9999999);
                txnid=randomNum.toString();
                firstname=etName.getText().toString();
                email=etEmail.getText().toString();
                amount=study_material_price;
                productinfo=study_material_name;
                phone=etPhone.getText().toString();
                String hashSequence = merchant_key+"|"+txnid+"|"+amount+"|"+productinfo+"|"+firstname+"|"+email+"|||||||||||"+salt;
                hash = hashCal("SHA-512", hashSequence);
                webview.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(), "PayUMoney");
                String json ="txnid="+txnid+"&key="+merchant_key+"&amount="+amount+"&hash="+hash+"&productinfo="+productinfo+"&surl="+SURL+"&furl="+FURL+"&firstname="+firstname+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&service_provider=payu_paisa";
                webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
                webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);       //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this
                //if ROM supports Multi-Touch
                webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                webview.setWebViewClient(
                        new SSLTolerentWebViewClient()
                        );
                webview.postUrl("https://secure.payu.in/_payment", EncodingUtils.getBytes(json, "BASE64"));

                try {

                    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {
                            Log.d("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode + " - " + description);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                            // handle different requests for different type of files
                            // this example handles downloads requests for .apk and .mp3 files
                            // everything else the webview can handle normally
                            if (url.endsWith(".mp3")||url.endsWith(".zip") || url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".jpg")|| url.endsWith(".doc")|| url.endsWith(".png")|| url.endsWith(".docx")|| url.endsWith(".xml")|| url.endsWith(".gif")) {
                                String urlSplit[] = url.split("/");
                                String fileName = urlSplit[urlSplit.length-1];
                                Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
                                // Make a new request pointing to the .apk url
                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                                // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
                                request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
                                request.setTitle(fileName);
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                }
                                // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
                                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName);
                                // get download service and enqueue file
                                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                manager.enqueue(request);
                            }
                            // if there is a link to anything else than .apk or .mp3 load the URL in the webview
                            else view.loadUrl(url);
                            return true;                
                        }
                    });


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all the fields.", 1000).show();
            }
        }
    });
}   

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(webview.canGoBack()){
                webview.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private final class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
    PayUJavaScriptInterface() {
    }

    /**
     * This is not called on the UI thread. Post a runnable to invoke
     * loadUrl on the UI thread.
     */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void success(long id, final String pId) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mHandler = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Transaction is Successful", 1000).show();
                status="Success";
                paymentId=pId;
                new StoreTransactionData().execute();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("status", "success");
                intent.putExtra("transaction_id", paymentId);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                studyDownloadPaid();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }



    @JavascriptInterface
    public void failure(final String id, String error) {
        Log.d("transaction data fail id", id +"   " +study_material_name);
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                paymentId=id;
                status="Faluire";
                new StoreTransactionData().execute();
                cancelPayment();
            }
        });
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void failure() {
        failure("");
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void failure(final String params) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                paymentId=params;
                status="Faluire";
                new StoreTransactionData().execute();
                Log.d("transaction data fail param", params);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("status", params);
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}

private void cancelPayment() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("status", "cancel");
    //mWebView.destroy();
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
    finish();
}

public static String hashCal(String type, String str) {
    byte[] hashseq = str.getBytes();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(hashseq);
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hexString.append("0");
            }
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    // Usually this should be a field rather than a method variable so
    // that it is not re-seeded every call.
    Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}


private class SSLTolerentWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }

}
```

Comment: where i need to call this PayUJavaScriptInterface?

Comment: In the activity where you load payment  url into webview

Comment: after this webView.postUrl(WebUrl.Bankurl, PostData.getBytes());,,, i need to call PayUJavaScriptInterface. am i right?

Comment: thank you now...i can navigate from  custom browser to my app...but  my issue is...before....after click the payment butoon i am getting one dialog with "processing your request " like that....now that is not coming. please tell me why the loading is not comming

Comment: i think you are missing to add something in your code please check your code

Comment: before,it is comin,,,now..only it is not showing. ok i willcheck again

Comment: Hello actually we using webview not custom browser you will see progress bar at top of the right side on the screen

Comment: but i want custom browser, customization. thats y i used this. so  i cant get that dialog from payu